# Displaying lastrow in listview

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

i have a column name Transaction Id and it is set to identity specification to Yes  .. and my question is how can i show the last Transaction Id in my Database to my Listview or in a Textbox ? thanks

Comment: What .NET language?  What RDBMS?  My answer assumed SQL Server and C#.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query to accomplish the desired output would be:

```
select top 1 TransactionId
from YourTransTable
order by TransactionId desc
```

And then just some quick C# code to set a TextBox's Text to the result:

```
int LastTransId;
SqlConnection DbConn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString);
SqlCommand ExecSql = new SqlCommand(string.Empty, DbConn);
ExecSql.CommandText = @"
    select top 1 TransactionId
    from YourTransTable
    order by TransactionId desc";

using (DbConn)
{
    DbConn.Open();
    using (ExecSql)
        LastTransId = Convert.ToInt32(ExecSql.ExecuteScalar());
}

YourTextBox.Text = LastTransId.ToString();
```